# How to change ratingStars to string?

Tags: android, rating

Im trying to translate RatingBar numOfStar() method into a string instead of an int. In tried to do numOfStar().ToString and it isnt possible.

How can i go about doing this. Because i want to save it as  a string in SQLite database.

```
public RatingBar ratingbar;


       ratingbar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

   private void saveState(){
 book_name = title.getText().toString();
 author = book_author.getText().toString();
 isbn = isbn_number.getText().toString();


 if(mRowId == null){
      long id = mDbHelper.addBook(book_name, author, isbn, ratings);

      if(id > 0 ){
          mRowId = id;

      }
  }else{
     mDbHelper.updateBooks(mRowId, book_name, author, ratings, isbn);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[String.valueOf(ratingbar.getRating())](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating%28%29)

[ratingbar.setRating(Float.valueOf("some string"))](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setRating%28float%29)

Comment: It wont let me do getRating().toString. It doesnt even give the option.

Comment: Than i assume you are not using RatingBar... it always had this method since API level 1.

Comment: Ok i have a rating bar called ratings_bar thats set to findViewByID. So when i do ratings_bar.getRating().  Nothing shows up after that. Nothing else is availabel.

Comment: I justed added some code. So you see my ratings bar. In the saveState() i wamt to save the rating stars to a string.. How can i do this?

Comment: Now click at the links i posted.

Comment: I did.. getRating will not let you set it to a string.. It says its a float.. Try it out in ecplise.the mehtod you provided  wont work.

Comment: Sorry... my bad. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I may need to see some more code so that I know what RatingBar numOfStar is defined as, although the toString method in Java starts with a lower case 't' which is important as Java is case-sensitive.

```
String stringResult = numOfStar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.valueOf(value)` to convert a primitive type to a String.